# ZF2 change extends class

Tags: php, zend-framework2, overriding, extending-classes

The answer to my question [ZF2 FormInput to show error class on validation fail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41716155/) is to create my own form view helper, overriding the `render` function. While this works beautifully for elements being rendered using `forminput`, it doesn't help on elements that inherit from `forminput`. For example, `FormCheckbox` inherits from `forminput` but not MY `forminput`:

```
<?php
namespace Zend\Form\View\Helper;
//...
class FormCheckbox extends FormInput {
    //...
}
```

In this case I would need to create ANOTHER form view helper for `formcheckbox` exclusively to extend MY `forminput`. And again for any other view helpers I want to include (`formdate`, `formemail`, `formpassword`, etc).

Instead of creating multiple view helpers is it possible to create a single view helper and tell ZF2 to use that in all calls to the original view helper when made by a ZF2 view helper?

i.e. `\Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormCheckbox` would extend `\RPK\Form\View\Helper\FormInput`, which would extend `\Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormInput`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using composer to install ZF2. As composer is generating my autoload functions I can specify an autoload path in the composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Zend\\Form\\View\\Helper\\": "vendor/rpk/Rpk/Form/View/Helper"
    }
},
```

This will search in my vendor folder for the class before looking in the zend folder.

This does not let me extend the FormInput, but calls my FormInput in its place. Calling extends on my FormInput puts the app into an infinite loop, so we need to copy the contents of FormInput into my class and make the changes there.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I can think of, is rewriting a part of the autoloader.

In the autoload function, you add an extra check to check if the requested class is `\Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormInput`, and if that's the case, you load your custom FormInput.

In your own FormInput you don't extend the Zend FormInput, but you create a copy of it, and modify the parts that are needed to be modified.

Unless ZF2 is using dependency injection for it's form helpers, this is the only way I can think of (without altering the base library code).

Answer (score 0):

What I have used are view partial. With partials you can define your own html for every input-element and you have access to all attributes and messages (e.g error-messages) of the input-element:

in your partial phtml:

```
<?php
    $options = $element->getOptions();
    $t = $this->t();
    $value = $element->getValue();
    $messages = $element->getMessages();
    $attr = $element->getAttributes();
```

you can use a partial like this:

```
$this->formRow($form->get('myelement'), null, null, 'mypartial');
```